# Changing citation color to blue in latex

Tags: hyperlink, latex, pdflatex

In my tex file i have added this package:

```
\usepackage[hidelinks, colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
```

I expect to have my citation links in blue color, but in the produced pdf all links are in green color! do you know why?

Answer (score 7):

Oh, I found I should add `citecolor=blue` and write it like this:

```
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
```